# Is the TFS_Warehouse database needed in TFS when reporting an analyzing is disabled?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I disabled reporting and analyzing in my TFS 2018

I also setup a backup process and I can see that only the configuration and my collection database are included.

Is the TFS_Warehouse database needed in TFS when reporting an analyzing is disabled? Can I delete the DB?

Answer (score 0):

This DB is no longer needed when reporting and analyzing is disabled. I deleted it and everything works fine.

Comment: Yes and you can recreate it at any time.